# Why percentage is not working properly in SQLite3?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sqlite

I have the following code for the following question however percentage is happening just to be zero:

```
SELECT p.state, (p.popestimate2011/sum(p.popestimate2011)) * 100
FROM pop_estimate_state_age_sex_race_origin p
WHERE p.age >= 21
GROUP BY p.state;
```

[image]

Also here's the table schema:

```
sqlite> .schema pop_estimate_state_age_sex_race_origin
CREATE TABLE pop_estimate_state_age_sex_race_origin (
   sumlev NUMBER, 
   region NUMBER, 
   division NUMBER, 
   state NUMBER, 
   sex NUMBER, 
   origin NUMBER, 
   race NUMBER, 
   age NUMBER, 
   census2010pop NUMBER, 
   estimatesbase2010 NUMBER, 
   popestimate2010 NUMBER, 
   popestimate2011 NUMBER, 
   PRIMARY KEY(state, age, sex, race, origin), 
   FOREIGN KEY(sumlev) REFERENCES SUMLEV(sumlev_cd), 
   FOREIGN KEY(region) REFERENCES REGION(region_cd), 
   FOREIGN KEY(division) REFERENCES DIVISION(division_cd), 
   FOREIGN KEY(sex) REFERENCES SEX(sex_cd), 
   FOREIGN KEY(race) REFERENCES RACE(race_cd), 
   FOREIGN KEY(origin) REFERENCES ORIGIN(origin_cd));
```

So when I run the query it just shows 0 for the percentage:

```
stat  p.popestimate
----  -------------
1     0            
2     0            
4     0            
5     0            
6     0            
8     0            
9     0            
10    0            
11    0            
12    0            
13    0            
15    0            
16    0            
17    0            
18    0            
19    0            
20    0            
21    0            
22    0            
23    0
```

I was trying to write it using nested queries by didn't get anywhere too:

```
    SELECT p.state, 100.0 * sum(p.popestimate2011) / total_pop AS percentage
FROM pop_estimate_state_age_sex_race_origin p
JOIN (SELECT state, sum(p2.popestimate2011) AS total_pop
      FROM pop_estimate_state_age_sex_race_origin p2) s ON (s.state = p.state)
WHERE age >= 21
GROUP BY p.state, total_pop
ORDER BY p.state;
```

The current problem I am having is that it just shows one row as result and just shows the result for the last state number (state ID=56):

```
56    0.131294163192301
```

Comment: Can you please give a hint rather than just voting down and closing the question? Can you also "BE NICE" as mentioned in codes of ethic in stackexchange? Not everyone knows everything!

Comment: Your task requires nested queries.

Comment: @PM77-1 can you please look at the end of my updated question? the nested query didn't work. Can you give any hint what's wrong?

Comment: Retracting downvote in the light of new edits. Sample data (and expected result) would be relevant. Add a GROUP BY clause in the subquery.

Comment: ... otherwise the inner query returns just one row with the sum of all rows along with a random state.

Comment: Why did you tag this with `postgresql` if you are clearly using SQLite?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach (not tested) that does not require an inner query.  It makes a single pass over the table, aggregating by state, and using `CASE` to calculate the numerator of population aged over 20 and denominator of total state population.

```
 SELECT 
    state,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN age >= 21 THEN popestimate2011 ELSE 0) / SUM(popestimate2011)) * 100
 FROM pop_estimate_state_age_sex_race_origin 
 GROUP BY state
```

Comment: Do you believe that OP wants intrastate percentages of adults vs. all?

Comment: Yes, it is my understanding that we are asked to calculate the percentage of adults in each state rather than the state's percentage contribution to the total adult population.

Answer (score 1):

<s>I'm not sure why your SQL statement is executing at all.  You are including the non-aggregated column value popestimate2011 in a `GROUP BY` select and that should generate an error.</s>

A closer reading of the SQLite documentation indicates that it *does*, in fact, support random value selection for non-aggregate columns in the result expression list (a feature also offered by MySQL).  This explains:

1. Why your `SELECT` statement is able to execute (a random value is chosen for the non-aggregated `popestimate2011` reference).
2. Why you are seeing a result of 0: the random value chosen is probably the first occurring row and if the rows were added to the database in order that row probably has an age value of 0.  Since the numerator in your division would then be 0, the result is also 0.

As to the meat of your calculation it's not clear from your table definition whether the data in your base table is *already* aggregated or not and, if so, what the `age` column represents (an average? the grouping factor for that row?)

Finally, SQLite does not have a `NUMBER` data type.  These columns will get the default affinity of `NUMERIC` which is probably what you want but might not be.

Comment: I was wondering about the legality of OP's script as well. I thought that only `MySQL` was so forgiving.

Comment: well, SQLite3 has NUMBER data type and so far I had no problem running rest of my queries.

Comment: @larry AGE is single-year of age (0, 1, 2, ...84, 85+ years).

Comment: I will only repeat that SQLite does *not* have a `NUMBER` data type (or, really any data types at all, so it's more accurate to state it doesn't have a `NUMBER` storage class).  The docs are here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html.

Comment: @PM77-1: Scouring the SQLite documentation I was able to determine that it does implement MySQL random-value logic for non-aggregated columns in `GROUP BY` queries (which came as a surprise to me).

Answer (score 0):

You need something along these lines (not tested):

```
SELECT state,  SUM(popestimate2011) / 
               (SELECT SUM(popestimate2011) 
                FROM pop_estimate_state_age_sex_race_origin 
                WHERE age > 21)))      
               * 100 as percentage
FROM pop_estimate_state_age_sex_race_origi
WHERE age >= 21
GROUP by state      
;
```

Comment: I think the `WHERE` clause on that inner query needs to be `WHERE state = OT.state` (where `OT` is an alias for the table in the outer query), and has to leave out the age.

Comment: @LarryLustig : My inner query is calculating an overall total (constant). It's **not** supposed to be a correlated query. As far as `WHERE` goes, my understanding was that we're comparing state's populations of adults against the total population of adults.

Comment: My understanding of the problem statement is that you're meant to calculate the percentage of *each state's* population that is over 21, not to calculate the percentage contribution that the state makes to the total population of adults.  Am I misreading?

Comment: @LarryLustig - I honestly do not know. May be I misunderstood what OP wants.

Comment: If I'm wrong, BTW, I retract my previous comment -- your query calculates the numbers as you've described.

Answer (score 0):

The NUMBER type does not exist in SQLite.
SQLite interprets as INTEGER and
decimals are lost in an integer division

```
(p.popestimate2011 / sum (p.popestimate2011))
```

is always 0.

Change the type of the column popestimate2011 REAL
or use CAST (...)

```
(CAST (p.popestimate2011 AS REAL) / SUM (p.popestimate2011))
```

Comment: While it's true that SQLite does not have a NUMBER type it's *not* true that NUMBER type declarations are treated as INT.  They are treated as NUMERIC which does *not* convert away decimals.  That is not the problem that's occurring here.